# concurrent query and insert have any side effect in android with objectbox?

Tags: multithreading, objectbox

In my android project, I use objectbox as database, if I insert with lock and query without lock, is there any side effect ? such as crash and so on.

```
    fun query(uniqueId: String = ""): MutableList<T> {
        if (box.store.isClosed) return mutableListOf()
        val query = box.query()
        withQueryBuilder(query, uniqueId)
        //开始
        return query.build().find()
}
private fun putInner(entity: T): Long {
    synchronized(box.store) {
        if (box.store.isClosed) return -1
        if (entity.unique.isBlank()) {
            entity.unique = entity.providerUnique()
        }
        entity.timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis()
        return try {
            box.put(entity).let { id -> entity.id = id }
            entity.id
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
           -1
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: above code run in multithread ,

Comment: There shouldn't be any issues in a multi-threaded environment. Just make sure to close a Query once done with it to release resources.